# Is it possible for the range of a matrix to be equal to the null space of its transpose? How does this have to do with real vs. complex?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A be a matrix with real entries. Is it possible that Ran(A) = Null(A<sup>t</sup>)? Does that change if it's a complex matrix?

Through browsing I've learned that the range of A should be orthogonal to the null space of A transposed, but I'm not sure how that exactly that is related to real vs. complex. We also haven't really gone over orthogonality in class (even though I am familiar to the concept), so theoretically this should be able to be solved without orthogonality.

I can see that a basis for the range of A relies on the pivot columns, and a basis for the null space of A transposed depends on the re-writing of the pivot rows of A transposed. I'm not sure how to proceed from here though. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $A^tA=0$, then for all $x$, $\|Ax\|^2 = x^tA^tAx=0$, hence $Ax=0$. It follows that $A00$.

Comment: How does that make the range equal to the kernel though? If I'm not mistaken the range in this case would just be 0, whereas the kernel would be the entire domain of A.

Comment: Never mind, got it. Thanks!

Comment: A quick example of a matrix which satisfies $A^TA = 0$:
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\i&0}
$$

Comment: Every real matrix is also a complex matrix.